# How to call a Rest Webservice and return json string in c#.net

Tags: c#, json, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I created a Rest Webservice with WebApi. This have 4 HTTP verbs. That is `Get,Post,Put,Delete`.
I want to call all these methods in webservice in C# window form application. It is not possible to add service reference for this Webservcie. How could i call GET,Post,put and delete method? I want to pass json string with `POST` request. Please help

Comment: can this help you? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/497123/How-to-make-REST-requests-with-Csharp

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call the service and pass along the POST data manually, and also manually parse the results, you can use [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx).